# How do I edit an SVG file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have to change the colour and produce a new SVG file depending on a value in the database.
The file I need to edit is in wwwroot\images\MapMarkers\blueMarker.svg.
I want to open it, & replace fill="#0000FF" with the appropriate colour, then save the new file for repeated use.

```
    var fileName = '..\..\images\MapMarkers\blueMarker.svg';
```

Comment: As it stands, your question is too broad. What problem are you having? Reading files? Writing files? Selecting an XML library? Manipulating XML with it? What JavaScript environment are you running in? NodeJS? Windows Scripting Host? Something else?

Comment: All of it. Firstly, how do I open the file. None of the examples given actually work.  I am using Typescript in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: "All of it." — Definitely too broad.

Comment: "I am using Typescript in an ASP.NET MVC application" — Does that means you are compiling the Typescript to JScript and then using that server side with ASP.NET? Or are you compiling it to JavaScript, delivering it to the client, and then running it in the browser?

Comment: How is this broad? I want to a) open a file, b) replace one string with another and c) save it as a new file.

Comment: "None of the examples given actually work" — What examples? Where is your [mcve]? What happens when you try to run them? Are there error messages? Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: "How is this broad?" — It's three separate problems … all of which come with large quantities of "It depends on your specific environment" in JS.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I think this is a pretty valuable question because wanting to brand svg (like illustrations) is becoming more popular.